# failing building with gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I created a project and I added the following to my `build.gradle` file, about which I got this error message `A problem occurred evaluating root project NewsFeeder. Plugin with id android not found`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '18'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the Android plugin docs for how to pull in the Android plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your complete build.gradle ?

If so, you are missing

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

usually above repositories block.

Also I think you need buildscript block to identify which gradle to be used.

Example build.gradle looks like

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 16
         targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    ..... other configs .....
}
```